# Is there a way to use gsutil while impersonating a service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am in the process of attempting to adjust user permissions in Google Cloud and have created a service account that other users can impersonate to access various projects. The `gcloud` command has the `--impersonate-service-account` option to make API calls with the proper authentication, but I was wondering if anyone knows how to make such calls using `gsutil`.

Here's an example of what a successful call looks like using `gcloud`:

```
gcloud --impersonate-service-account=superuser@PROJECT1.iam.gserviceaccount.com iam service-accounts list --project PROJECT2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, here's the option:

```
$ gsutil -i [SERVICE-ACCOUNT]@[PROJECT] [GSUTIL-COMMAND]
```

Example:

```
$ gsutil -i myserviceaccount@iam.gserviceaccount.com ls
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such option in the [top-level gsutil command-line options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions) (at least not a documented one).

By contrast the gcloud [--impersonate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--impersonate-service-account) is documented.

Things to try:

- if you use the `gsutil` distributed with the gcloud SDK - it has some ability to use the credentials established by `gcloud auth`, see [Configuring/Using Credentials Via Cloud Sdk Distribution Of Gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CredentialTypesSupportingVariousUseCases?#configuringusing-credentials-via-cloud-sdk-distribution-of-gsutil)
- if you use the standalone version, check the [`gsutil config`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config) command, which should allow specifying a service account credentials (see also [Updating To The Latest Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config#updating-to-the-latest-configuration-file)):

> **-e** Prompt for service account credentials. This option requires that -a is not set.

Comment: I previously tried the things you suggested and have come to a similar conclusion that as of now, no such feature exists. I opened this issue on the gsutil github project: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/813 Thanks!